# how to get user name by using api angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

in my project i have login page that allows me to access the menu dashboard as shown by the code, in the menu dashboard i have icon with text welcome james the name of the user, so all i need that when i login with email and password i want in the menu dashboard to get the name of user connected for example welcome james.

the code :

login code html:

```
<h1 style="text-align:center">
  <img src="../../assets/images/logo.png">
</h1>
<div class="login-wrap">
  <div class="login-html">

    <div class='login'>
      <div class='col-md-4 offset-4 mt-5' *ngIf='!this.isLogin'>
        <h2 class="login-header">S'identifier</h2>
        <form class="login-container" #myform="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myform)">
          <div class='form-group'>
            <input class='form-control' type="email" name="email" placeholder="email" ngModel>
          </div>

          <div class='form-group'>
            <input class='form-control' type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"
              [type]="hide ? 'password': 'text'" [(ngModel)]="passwordValue">
            <span class="material-icons" matSuffix (click)="hide = !hide">
              {{hide ? 'visibility': 'visibility_off'}}
            </span>
          </div>
          <input class='btn btn-outline-info' type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class='col-md-4 offset-4 mt-5' *ngIf='this.isLogin'>

        <h1>You are logged in</h1>
        <button class='btn btn-outline-info' (click)='logout()'>Log-out</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

login.ts:

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  isLogin: boolean = false
  errorMessage: any
  hide =true;
  passwordValue='';

  constructor(
    private _api: ApiService, 
    private _auth: AuthService, 
    private _router:Router,  private toastr : ToastrService) { }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.isUserLogin(); 
  }
  
  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    
    console.log('Your form data : ', form.value);
    this._api.postTypeRequest('user/login', form.value).subscribe((res: any) => {
     
      switch (res.status) {
        case 0:
            this.toastr.error("you have a problem","Erreur");
            break;
        case 1:
            this._auth.setDataInLocalStorage('userData', JSON.stringify(res.data));  
            this._auth.setDataInLocalStorage('token', res.token);  
            this._router.navigate(['']);
            break;
        case 2:
            this.toastr.warning("your email or password is incorrect","Warning");
            this.passwordValue = '';
            break;
    }
    })
  }

  isUserLogin(){
    if(this._auth.getUserDetails() != null){
        this.isLogin = true;
    }
  }

  logout(){
    this._auth.clearStorage()
    this._router.navigate(['']);
  }
}
```

component.html :

```
<nav class="menu">
    <ol>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Home</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a routerLink="adherents">Adherents</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item">
            <a routerLink="factures">Factures</a>
            <ol class="sub-menu">
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Suivi</a></li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
            <a routerLink="logs">Logs</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
            <a routerLink="regions">Regions</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
            <a routerLink="roles">Roles</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
            <img class="img" src="../assets/images/user.png">
            <a>welcome james</a>
            <ol class="sub-menu">
                <li class="menu-item"><a routerLink="/login">LougOut</a></li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

auth.service.ts :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  constructor() { }


  getUserDetails() {
    if(localStorage.getItem('userData')){
      return localStorage.getItem('userData')
    }else{
      return null
    }
    
  }
  setDataInLocalStorage(variableName, data) {
      localStorage.setItem(variableName, data);
  }
  getToken() {
      return localStorage.getItem('token');
  }
  clearStorage() {
      localStorage.clear();
  }
  
}
```

api.service.ts :

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {
  baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/';

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

  getTypeRequest(url) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','application/json');
    return this._http.get(`${this.baseUrl}${url}`, {headers}).pipe(map(res => {
      return res;
    }));
  }
  postTypeRequest(url, payload) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','application/json');
    return this._http.post(`${this.baseUrl}${url}`, payload, {headers}).pipe(map(res => {
      return res;
    }));
  }

}
```

Comment: Either specify the question more or provide some information about what you already tried

Comment: From the looks of it, in `component.ts` you will have to get the `userData` key from the localStorage, then deserialize it and get the name of the user (assuming the username is contained within the userdata object). After that you should be able to show it in the welcome message. With that said though, I would recommend using a state management library like NGXS to centralize information about the logged in user.

Comment: @MateusSchneiders how to do that